# Launch Service register application bundle

Tags: macos, bundle

I have some internal application bundles inside my main application bundle (in Resources). After installing (with Installer), my application is placed in /Applications, but I can't find my "internal" application by their bundle ids.

If I manually go to the /Applications, select my application and navigate to its content in Finder, my "internal" application became visible.

I know that `lsregister` is responsible to register application bundles, I have this script in my postflight in pkg:

```
SREGISTER="/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister"

$LSREGISTER "/Applications/MY.app/Contents/Resources/MyMini.app"
```

But I need administration privileges in my installer, that's why this command is executed by root and does no effect to current user.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no solution for this. Because I need to run the `lsreginster` for every user of the system, and newly created users after the installation will not see this helpers app.

The only way is put this application outside the main bundle (in subdirectory of the /Applications for example)

Answer (score 1):

You could register your helper apps the first time your main app runs, rather than during installation.  You'll need to find them by name and location rather than bundle ID.  And instead of using the `lsregister` tool, you can use the `LSRegisterURL` function.  Remember that an `NSURL*` can be cast to a `CFURLRef` by toll-free bridging.

Comment: I need to register my helpers apps during installation because they will be used in other applications by their bundle ids (and perhaps before first run of the main app).